# How to check if textbox is empty and display a popup message if it is using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textbox

I'm trying to check if the textbox is empty for my form. However, whenever I try to hit submit instead of an alert box message, telling me Firstname is empty I get "Please fill out filled".

```js
('#submit').click(function() {
  if ($('#firstname').val() == '') {
    alert('Firstname is empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="elem" autocomplete="on">
  First Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required placeholder="Enter the first name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: change type of button from `submit` to `button`

Comment: You seem to be missing the `$` on your jQuery object

Comment: If you want a simple validation, you can use [`required`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute

Comment: @CarlJan he is, that's the issue

Comment: I think this question is related to a typo and it should be closed. `required` attribute is an HTML5 attribute, if you remove that you should get rid of the message you say about in your question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see, didn't read much, just skimmed it

Comment: @guradio if I use button it doesn't validate what I enter in the textbox that's why I'm using submit and I am using pattern.

Comment: If you are already cvalidating in the input field you do not require to validate again using jquery and since you miss `$` before `('#submit')` your jquery errors out and hence the input validation tells you to fill the required field

Comment: Change `('#submit')` to `$('#submit')` - I tried this in a new snippet and it seemed to work ok.   I would still return false to cancel the default submit, but you get your messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'm assuming that the missing `$` is just a typo in the question, as you state that you see the validation message appear.

The reason you're seeing the 'Please fill out this field' notification is because you've used the `required` attribute on the field. If you want to validate the form manually then remove that attribute. You will also need to hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of the `button` and prevent the form submission if the validation fails, something like this:

```js
$('#elem').submit(function(e) {
  if ($('#firstname').val().trim() == '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Firstname is empty');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="elem" autocomplete="on">
  First Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter the first name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Personally I'd suggest you use the `required` attribute as it saves all of the above needless JS code - unless you need more complex logic than just checking all required fields have been given values.

Comment: Try the original, just with `$` added (what appears to be a typo) - works fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m in Chrome you only see the `alert()`, but in Firefox (and possibly others, I haven't tested all browsers) you see the `alert()` and also the HTML5 validation notification. The above stops that behaviour. You can try the OPs fixed original code here: https://jsfiddle.net/rgzq2stw/

Comment: Yes, I'm lazy and only work in a viable browser... :)  I did wonder as I would have expected to get the required field validation as well given that it was a submit (so maybe chrome is wrong here?)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you! I deleted required function on my html file since I do not need anything complex than this. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @박두준 no problem, glad to help

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, I'd agree that I think Chrome is wrong here. If you've set `required` then the notification should appear, regardless of any event handlers on the element.

Comment: this is not a right way, because if you will use two empty strings like '  ', your code will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the **required** property set.It is giving you **Please fill out field validation** as the error message.It is the validation that HTML5 is performing.

Answer (score 0):

For this please make one function like :

```
function Checktext()
{
 if ($('#firstname').val() == '') {
 alert('Firstname is empty');
return false;
}

else
{
return true;
}
}
```

now call this function on submit button click like :

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return check();" />
```

Comment: Unobtrusive event handlers, like the OP is already using, are much better than the outdated `on*` event attributes in every possible way